# Whether SQL standard edition has NUMA support?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019, numa

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017#RDBMSSP

For `NUMA Aware Large Page Memory and Buffer Array Allocation` the table says No

And further below it says:

> Standard Edition and SQL Server + CAL-based licensing can restrict how
> many processors SQL Server Standard can use, but SQL Server Standard
> is NUMA aware.

This question is to ask whether SQL standard edition (2016, 2017, 2019) has NUMA support because the table and the above quote show conflicting information.

The table for SQL server 2017 and 2019 say No without any quote. So was NUMA supported in 2016 and not supported in 2017 & 2019?

Links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-2017#RDBMSSP

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017#RDBMSSP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This question is to ask whether SQL standard edition (2016, 2017, 2019) has NUMA support [...]

Yes, it does. Take a few seconds to look at the errorlog and you'll find out. Simple repro, takes maybe a minute.

Comment: Yes I tried it on 2019 standard edition, but what's confusing me is that the above table says its not supported.

Comment: The table doesn't say NUMA, it says "NUMA Aware Large Page Memory and Buffer Array Allocation ". If your car takes 93 octane gas, you _wouldn't say it doesn't take gas_, you'd say it doesn't take anything lower than 93.

Comment: It's not a simple repro if you don't have a SQL standard license installed on the target hardware already.  I don't find the octane analogy to clarify things; if anything my understanding is that it would be similar to cars that take 93 octane gas *but can still run on 87 with reduced performance* (e.g. by retarding timing).  In this analogy the car being a NUMA server, SQL Enterprise being 93 octane, and SQL Standard being 87

Comment: I didn't make an octane analogy. I'm not sure what you're talking about. I also don't know why there needed to be a new answer to a question that was already answered a year and a half ago.

Comment: There's a comment that says "If your car takes 93 octane gas..."
I had the same question when preparing a new installation, and was hoping I could find the answer.  Since I didn't find one, I did more research and added one.  I suppose it was downvoted out of spite.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server Standard *supports* NUMA, in that it will run correctly on NUMA hardware; what this is talking about:

> NUMA Aware Large Page Memory and Buffer Array Allocation

is "optimizing" for NUMA

See here for a related question:
[How to measure the performance improvement that NUMA brings?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/112828/110446), this being the relevant piece:

> Versions of SQL Server that are NUMA aware/optimized will try to keep memory usage within the same local NUMA node to avoid the hops [which hurt performance]...You can also track remote node access from perfmon using the SQL Server:Buffer Node\Remote node page lockups/sec counter.

It's not clear why they removed the clarifying language after SQL 2016

Comment: See also https://thomaslarock.com/2019/01/yes-sql-server-standard-edition-is-numa-aware/